# How to find multiple phrases within a single string?

Tags: python

So far

```
s = 'the fish walked start234stop down to the start879stop kajsdasdas'
result = re.findall('start(.*)stop', s)
print(result)
```

results in

> **['234stop down to the start879']**

and the intended result was

> **['234']**
>
> **[' 879']**

Is there an elegant way to achieve this? Although currently its only needing to handle 2 phrases, my intentions are for it to output as many phrases as it finds, each formatted in this way.

Comment: `re.findall('start(.*?)stop', s)` ?

Comment: If you know that between `start` and `stop` there is always an integer, you can use `'(start)(\\d+)(stop)'`

Answer (score 2):

You are matching too much because the `*` character is greedy. This means that it will match as much as it can before the end of the search, so only stopping when it finds the last `stop` in your searchable string.

You can make the star 'non-greedy' by suffixing it with a question mark. That way it will stop matching as soon as it finds the first 'stop' after it started matching.

```
result = re.findall('start(.*?)stop', s)
```